# How to solve $2^x +3^y =7 $ and $2x-3y=1$

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

How to solve $2^x +3^y =7 $ and $2x-3y=1$

It is easy to see that, $x=2 $ and $y=1$ are solutions to the equations.

But how can I solve it?

Comment: Why do you think an elementary solution to the generalized problem should be possible?  Mixing exponentials and polynomials and looking for solutions screams [transcendental equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) to me which more often than not will have [non-elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function#Non-elementary_functions) solutions.

Comment: It's "really" more like a polynomial but with an irrational exponent.  That is, if $z = 2^x$, after substituting $y = (2x-1)/3$ you get $$ z + 3^{-1/3} z^\alpha = 7$$ where $\alpha = (2/3) \log_2(3)$.

Answer (score 6):

Because $2x-3y=1$, we know that $x = \frac{1+3y}{2}$. Then $2^x+3^y = 7$ becomes
$$2^{(1+3y)/2}+3^y=7$$
so it suffices to solve the above equation. Observe that the function
$$f(y) = 2^{(1+3y)/2}+3^y$$
is increasing (exponential functions with base $>1$ are increasing, and the sum of two increasing functions is increasing). In particular, it is a one-to-one function, so there is a unique $y$ for which
$$2^{(1+3y)/2}+3^y=7.$$
You've already found that $y=1$ is such a solution, so it is the only solution. (And $x$ is determined uniquely from $y$ as above.)

Comment: "*You've already found that $y=1$ is such a solution*"... and if the numbers were ever so slightly different?  What then?  What if for whatever reason the OP had *not* recognized $y=1$ was a solution by inspection?  The general solution of $a^{p(y)}+b^{y}=c$ for $y$ given $a,b,c,p$ doesn't exist with elementary functions.  I read the question as asking how to have found $y=1$ in the first place *without* inspection.

Comment: what if there are no clear solutions at all ?

Comment: @AngeloMark In the general case, I don't think there is an elementary solution. See, e.g., [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436907/inverse-function-of-sum-of-exponential-function). Numerically, you can always determine whether there is a solution or not, and if there is a solution, you can approximate it arbitrarily closely. But an *exact* solution is not likely except in particular cases.

Comment: @Jmoravitz If the explicit solution exist, then it should be expressed with Lambert $W$. (my opinition)

Comment: @lonestudent No, it has nothing to do with Lambert W.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I wanted to say the worst (if there exist)...  Then there is no explicit solution.  Am I right? If there is an exact solution, what kind of a function can this be? The only method I can know in exponential transcendental solutions is Lambert

Comment: As far as I know there is no closed form for the solutions, whether using Lambert W or not.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of complex solutions to this system looks interesting.  Here are some of the $y$ values:

[image]

Comment: (+) Can you give a little information..Which software did you use, Maple, Mathematica, or another?

Comment: This is using the command Analytic in the RootFinding package of Maple.

Comment: Thank you for share.

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it, let me make the problem more general
$$2^x +3^y =k \qquad \text{and} \qquad 2x-3y=1$$ As @Robert Israel commented, make $z=2^x$ and,as he wrote, the problem is no< to find the zero of function
$$f(z)=z+3^{-\frac 13} z^\alpha-k\qquad \text{where} \qquad \alpha=\frac{2 \log (3)}{3 \log (2)}$$ $\alpha$ is very close to $1$ (this makes $f(x)$ to be very close to a straight line) and then, for any $k$, we can *approximate* the solution using
$$z_0=\frac{3 k}{3+3^{2/3}}$$ Making a single iteration of Newton method, we have
$$z_1=\frac{z_0 \left(3 k+3^{2/3} (\alpha -1) z_0^{\alpha }\right)}{3^{2/3} \alpha  z_0^{\alpha   }+3 z_0}$$

Some results for a few values of $k$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 k & z_0 & z_1 & \text{solution} \\
  1 & 0.59054 & 0.59758 &  0.59757 \\
  2 & 1.18108 & 1.17662 &  1.17662 \\
  3 & 1.77162 & 1.74860 &  1.74860 \\
  4 & 2.36217 & 2.31598 &  2.31597 \\
  5 & 2.95271 & 2.87992 &  2.87990 \\
  6 & 3.54325 & 3.44113 &  3.44109 \\
 7  & 4.13379 & 4.00005 &  4.00000 \\
 8  & 4.72433 & 4.55703 &  4.55695 \\
 9  & 5.31487 & 5.11230 &  5.11220 \\
 10 & 5.90541 & 5.66605 &  5.66592 \\
 11 & 6.49596 & 6.21843 &  6.21828 \\
 12 & 7.08650 & 6.76957 &  6.76939 \\
 13 & 7.67704 & 7.31957 &  7.31936 \\
 14 & 8.26758 & 7.86852 &  7.86827
\end{array}
\right)$$